# The Apache axis2 jar files are not taking at run time

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, axis

While running the application I was getting the following errors. The error is getting at run time only. It has compiled successfully.

It ran under eclipse without any issues. But with Apache axis we are getting following error trace while uploading to server. The Apache axis2 jar files are not taking at run time.But compiling successfully.

The application is running under Oracle R12 server.I didn't find any option to set class path for run time in R12 server.

Using Java version is 1.6 and Apache axis2.1.6.2

Error trace:

```
Exception :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService
Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService
com.rightnow.ws.wsdl.RightNowSyncServiceStub.populateAxisService(RightNowSyncServiceStub.java:41)
com.rightnow.ws.wsdl.RightNowSyncServiceStub.(RightNowSyncServiceStub.java:636)
com.rightnow.ws.wsdl.RightNowSyncServiceStub.(RightNowSyncServiceStub.java:625)
com.rightnow.ws.wsdl.RightNowSyncServiceStub.(RightNowSyncServiceStub.java:673)
com.rightnow.ws.wsdl.RightNowSyncServiceStub.(RightNowSyncServiceStub.java:665)
com.rightnow.ws.util.ContactUtils.initializeService(ContactUtils.java:57)
_somejsp._jspService(_somejsp.java:189)
com.orionserver.http.OrionHttpJspPage.service(OrionHttpJspPage.java:59)
oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:473)
oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:594)
oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:518)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
oracle.apps.jtf.base.session.ReleaseResFilter.doFilter(ReleaseResFilter.java:26)
com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:15)
oracle.apps.fnd.security.AppsServletFilter.doFilter(AppsServletFilter.java:318)
com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:642)
com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:313)
com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:199)
oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.I believe there should be axis.jar missing or misplaced in your sever.check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all axis2 related libraries either in your server's lib directory, or they need to come packaged with your .war file.

To take care of this in eclipse, select your project and go to

Properties-> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entries

and add all the axis2 jars. This will ensure that all relevant jars are bundled together with your .war

Another solution is to hardcopy all the axis2 jars into WebContent/WEB-INF/lib